# How I can management private files

Tags: 7, files

My default download method is public, but I need save some file on private folder, I am doing this:

```
//...
$file = file_save_data($handle, 'private://example.zip', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
//...
```

Now when I try show to download it:

```
//...
$file = file_load($file_fid);
$url = file_create_url($file->uri);

$output['download'] = [
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => l(t('Download'), $url),
];

return $output;
//...
```

If I do click on the url, I get:

> Access denied. You are not authorized to access this page.

I am superadmin (uid = 1). How I can management those files for me and for others users?

Comment: Private files are not meant to be used like that. Check your [docs](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/file#content-accessing-private-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bypass Drupal permission, you can implements hook_file_download():

```
/**
 * Implements hook_file_download().
 */
function mymodule_file_download($uri) {
  if (someCondition()) {
    if (!user_access('some permissions')) {
      // Access to the file is denied.
      return -1;
    }
    else {
      return array('Content-Type' => file_get_mimetype($uri));
    }
  }
}
```